# How to set fillMaxWidth() for all childs in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**My problem:**

I have multiple TextField in same page. I give the fillMaxWidth() in my rootView(column).
But all child views width take it as wrap_content.

**My code:**

```
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()//I give the max width here
        .fillMaxHeight()
) {

       MyTextField1()// No modifiers used
       MyTextField2()
       ...
 }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**My question:**

I have list of TextFields. So code simplicity I want to handle within rootView.
It's any other option to fill the width for all child views?

Comment: Your child views `MyTextField1()` should also have `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`.

Comment: @SreekantShenoy ohh ok thanks. I thought some other options available to handle within rootView.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add some modifier which will be applied to all children without passing it directly.

But using `Layout` you can create custom column which will make all children fill max width and add spacing between:

```
@Composable
fun ColumnFillChildrenWidth(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    spacing: Dp = 0.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        var yOffset = 0
        val placeablesWithOffset = measurables.map {  measurable ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            val result = placeable to yOffset
            yOffset += placeable.height + spacing.toPx().toInt()
            result
        }

        val totalViewHeight = placeablesWithOffset.sumOf { it.first.height }
        val totalSpacing = ((measurables.size - 1) * spacing.toPx()).roundToInt()
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = totalViewHeight + totalSpacing
        ) {
            placeablesWithOffset.forEach {
                val (placeable, offset) = it
                placeable.place(0, offset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ColumnFillChildrenWidth(
    spacing = 20.dp,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(20.dp)
) {
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. I will check and let you know

Comment: have you let him know @Ranjithkumar ?

Comment: The column doesn't seem to scale to the correct size when adding multiple views with spacing and padding. The last view will be partially out of bounds. It seems to be caused by the spacing. Can you please update your answer with a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a modifier variable using `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` and pass it to all child TextFields.

```
Column(
  ...
) {
    val maxWidthModifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

    MyTextField1(maxWidthModifier)
    MyTextField2(maxWidthModifier)
    ...
}
```

...here applies.

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField1(modifier: Modifier) {
    TextField(
        ...
        //apply modifier
        modifier = modifier
    )
}
```